# MPAndroidChart - Zoom or scale in x resolution at all visible line charts

Tags: java, android, charts, linechart, mpandroidchart

I have up to 12 visible linecharts at the same time. Everyone is showing 1 analog or digital signal in realtime. Now I want to scale X-resolution with a pinch, (this is already working on a single line chart) but now all linecharts should zoom at the same time an the same scale factor.

[image]

I tried it with a onTouchListener on each linechart, if anyone is touched and scaled, it is tellig it´s scale to the other one.

```
LineChartObject ob = mLineChartObj.get(lineChartObj);

if (ob.lineChart == null)
//    new LineChart
  ob.lineChart = new LineChart(mContext);
ob.lineChart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float[] val = {ob.lineChart.getScaleX(), ob.lineChart.getScaleY(), ob.lineChart.getX(), ob.lineChart.getY()};

    for(int i=0; i<mLineChartObj.size(); i++){
      if(i == lineChartObj)
        continue;
      mLineChartObj.get(i).lineChart.setScaleX(val[0]); //zoom(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

I take the scaleX of the actual touched linechart, and give it to the other one, but this doesn't work.

Maybe you know how to solve this issue.

EDIT 1: ######################################################

I tried this code...I have observed the printLines and noticed that the scaleX gets bigger the more I zoom in with touch gestures. As would be expected scaleX gets smaller the more I zoom out with gestures. As well in Y direction, the scaleY gets bigger or smaller.

BUT !! The linechart I call zoom(val[0], val[1 ],....) is only zooming in, although the scaleX/scaleY gets smaller !!

```
  ob.lineChart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float[] val = {ob.lineChart.getScaleX(), ob.lineChart.getScaleY(), ob.lineChart.getWidth() / 2, ob.lineChart.getHeight() / 2};
    for (int i = 0; i < mLineChartObj.size(); i++) {
      if (i == lineChartObj)
        continue;

      mLineChartObj.get(i).zoomCounter++;
//          zoomCounter to get a slower zoom
      if (mLineChartObj.get(i).zoomCounter % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println("§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§");
        System.out.println("scaleX: " + val[0]);
        System.out.println("scaleY: " + val[1]);
        System.out.println("Width/2: " + val[2]);
        System.out.println("Height/2: " + val[3]);
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        mLineChartObj.get(i).lineChart.zoom(val[0], val[1], mLineChartObj.get(i).lineChart.getWidth() / 2, mLineChartObj.get(i).lineChart.getHeight() / 2); //zoom(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
        System.out.println(val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + val[2] + " " + val[3]);
        System.out.println(val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + mLineChartObj.get(i).lineChart.getWidth() / 2 + " " + mLineChartObj.get(i).lineChart.getHeight() / 2);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [tutorial on interaction with the charts](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart). The library provides a listener concept (`OnChartGestureListener`) that allows to react on gestures such as panning or zooming that are performed on the chart.

So what you could do is set a listener to the chart that is zoomed, and then in the callback methods from the listener zoom the other charts as well.

Comment: Wow, I got the right one xD... Phil "the master of charts" Jay...Zomming with a pinch works quite well, but getting the scaleX value and give it to the other charts doesn't work. I used .getScaleX at the touched one and then I gave this value to the others with .setScaleX(<scaleXvalue>);

Comment: no more ideas ?? ( again: lineChart2.setScaleX(lineChart1.getScaleX()); doesn't work )

Comment: check out the zoom(...) methods the chart provides